# swift - Call a function between collectionview cell class and collectionview Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, collectionview

Hi i have been struggle with this probleme for some time and cant figure it out.

What i would like to do is, press a button inside a collectionview cell, and perform a transition to next cell.

This is the function i want to call that is inside the the collectionview controller class:

```
func done(){
    let scrollIndex: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)// NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
    CollectionViewet.scrollToItem(at: scrollIndex as IndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

What happens is that when i call a function from collectionview controller, it give me this

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `UICollectionViewController` has a subview by default called `collectionView` which you should use to scroll to an item

So if you override the data source delegate methods properly you should be able to scroll as follows

```
func done() {

    let numberOfRows = collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) ?? 0

    guard numberOfRows > 1 else { return }

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)

    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

I added the `guard` line to prevent the app from crashing in case of an empty data for some reason.